# 専用サーバーを利用することで仮想サーバーよりもホスティング業者からの攻撃への保護が追加されますか

Tags: security

サーバーの選定にあたってVPS、クラウド、専用サーバーのキーワードで調べていたら以下の記述を見つけました:

[匿名VPNの｢ibVPN｣をおすすめしないこれだけの理由](http://tengoku.livedoor.biz/archives/6686811.html)

> クラウドやVPSを積極的に利用し、ランニングコストを抑えています。 もちろん専用サーバも中にはあるのでしょうが、混ぜている時点で不可。
> いくらクラウド/VPS上でノーログだとしても、ホスティング会社へのオーダーで接続状況を記録される可能性は否定できません。
> Abuseのメールにしても、まずはWhoisに記載のあるホスティング会社へ届き、それが顧客であるibVPNに転送されるというシステムですので、令状に関しては把握すらできない可能性があります。

記事では「ホスティング会社へのオーダーで接続状況を記録される可能性」があることから、VPS/クラウドより専用サーバーがセキュリティ上よりよい選択（VPS/クラウドは不可）ということを言っているようです。

ただ自分はここに疑問があります。ホスティング業者を信用しない（つまりホスティング業者が悪意を持って自身の購入したサーバーを攻撃してくる）状況で、かつ、ホスティング業者の攻撃からサーバーを保護したいなら、VPSやクラウド、専用サーバーのどれを選んでも、結局サーバー自体はホスティング会社が持っているので追加の保護は得られないのではありませんか？

ホスティング会社へのオーダーで接続状況を記録される可能性は、仮想サーバーも専用サーバーも物理サーバーはホスティング会社にあるので同じはずですし、「Abuseのメールにしても、まずはWhoisに記載のあるホスティング会社へ届き」という作業も同じはずではないでしょうか？

Comment: そのサイトの内容はVPNのゲートウェイに対する議論で「一般論としてのセキュリティの優劣」「サーバに対する事業者による攻撃」の検討はしていません。 論点にぶれがあると回答もトンチンカンなものになるので、サイトは無視してあなたの聞きたいことの質問にするか、サイトの内容に沿った質問にするか見直してみてください。なお、そのサイトの記載は正確とは言い難いので、後者は避けた方がよいかと思います

Answer (score 3, accepted):

まず、記事はVPNを利用する場合の話です。後半のabuseのメールについては、利用しているVPNの会社が信用できない場合、VPN経由での通信に関する法的な連絡が来ない可能性があるという事になります。単純にAWS等のクラウドを利用したい場合とは少し異なるので注意が必要です。

VPSやクラウド、専用サーバーを借りる場合に気にしているのは次の二つだと思います。

1. abuseのメールが握る潰されることは無いのか？
2. 何かしらの通信ログの取得や情報を取得されるのでは無いのか？

それぞれについて回答します。

### abuseのメールが握り潰されることは無いのか？

迷惑メールなどの被害を被った組織がabuseのメールを送る場合、その宛先は、「ドメイン」と「IPアドレス」のどちらか、または、両方になることでしょう。

「ドメイン」については、ほとんどのサービスで独自ドメインを設定することができますので、独自ドメインを使用していれば、その独自ドメイン宛になるはずです。ホスティング業者が信頼できないのであれば、メールサーバーを別にしておけば、握りつぶされると言うことはないでしょう。

「IPアドレス」ですが、こちらはドメインと同様に自社が所有するIPアドレスを割り当てると言うことが可能な場合があります(AWSのBYOIP等)。自社が所有するIPアドレスであるため、whoisにかかれた連絡先はホスティング業者ではなく自社になります。abuseのメールもそちらに送られるため、ホスティング業者が握りつぶすと言うことはありません。

難点として、すでにIPアドレスを持っていない場合、IPv4アドレスを新たに入手することが困難かつ高額になっています。また、利用するクラウドや接続形態によっては不可能だったり、オンプレミス側にルーター等の装置が必要になる場合があります。

よって、VPSでもクラウドでも専用サーバーでも、「ドメイン」も「IPアドレス」も自社で用意したものにし、メールサーバーを別途用意しているのであれば、abuseのメールが届かない、握りつぶされる、なんてことにはなりません。逆に、専用サーバーであっても、業者が用意した「ドメイン」と「IPアドレス」を使う場合は、abuseのメールは業者に送られるため、業者から連絡が来ないと言うことはあり得ることになります。

### 何かしらの通信ログの取得や情報を取得されるのでは無いのか？

VPSやクラクドは仮想環境技術を用いて、物理サーバー(ホスト)上にある仮想マシン(ゲスト)を提供する形(IaaS)です(クラウドの場合はサービスによってIaaS以外の場合もありますが、似たようなものなので今は省きます。)仮想環境では、ホストからゲストは丸見えです。それこそ、復号化された情報や暗号鍵が存在するメモリ情報を含めてアクセス可能です。通信内容だって取り放題です。つまり、ホスティング業者に悪意があれば、暗号化とかをどれだけ施しても、情報は丸見えと言うことです(これを防ぐにはクライアントサイド暗号化ぐらいしか方法はありません)。

ひとまず、ホスティング業者は信頼するとしても、まだ問題があります。上の話はホストからゲストであって、基本的にゲストからゲストからは見えないはずなのですが、仮想環境ホストの不具合により、ゲストから別のゲストのメモリ情報が取得できてしまうと言う脆弱性が発見されることがあります。まともなホスティング業者であれば、すぐにパッチを適用することでしょうが、ゼロデイ脆弱性だった場合などはどうしてもタイムラグがあります。そのような状態で同じホストに悪意ある人が借りているゲストがいた場合どうなるでしょう。そう、あなたのサーバーの情報を取得できてしまう可能性があると言うことです。(悪意ある他者からの攻撃は、自社専用の仮想的なクラウドを間借りする「ホスティング型プライベートクラウド」である程度は防ぐことができる場合があります。)

専用サーバーであれば、上記のようなホストからゲストやゲスト同士の情報取得などの心配をする必要はありません。ただ、次のような事には注意が必要です。

- ネットワーク装置はホスティング業者が用意しているため、ネットワーク通信の全ての内容を取得可能です。
- ホスティング業者はサーバーへ物理的なアクセスが可能です。つまり、ディスクを抜き出して、コピーすれば、ディスク内の暗号化されていない全て取得することができます。物理的なスイッチによる強制ダンプなどの機能を用いることで、メモリ情報も取得できます。そもそも、OSによってはroot権限取得も可能(Linux等ではコンソールとレスキュー用CD/DVDからの起動で管理者パスワードのリセットが可能)です。VPSやクラウドとは違ってこっそりすることは難しいかもしませんが、取得する方法はいくらでもあります。

結局は、悪意あるホスティング業者からの攻撃を完全に守れる方法はありません。

### まとめ

abuseのメールについては、独自の「ドメイン」「IPアドレス」を用いて、メールサーバーを別に用意すれば、VPS/クラウド/専用サーバーのいずれであっても問題ないでしょう。ただ、独自「IPアドレス」については、IPアドレスの用意や利用できるサービスが限られる等、手軽にできるとは言えないので注意が必要です。

もし、ホスティング業者を全く信頼できないのであれば、何をしても情報の保護を完全に行うことはできません。完全な保護を望むのであれば、自社のサーバー室内にオンプレミスで構築する以外の選択肢はありません。ただ、オンプレミスであっても、構築を依頼した業者がバックドアを仕込む可能性や運用を依頼した業者が悪意を持っている可能性もあります。そもそも、購入したサーバー等の機器にバックドアが仕込んである可能性もあります。また、データセンターに比べて、自社内のサーバー室の方がセキュリティ(監視カメラ、入退室管理、ビル自体の警備体制等)が低い可能性も高いです。それらを防ぎたいとなると、高額な施設の用意と構築・運用が可能な技術レベルが高い従業員の常時雇用が必要になり、コストがかなり高くなります。